# Required bundle manifest headers do not exist wso2

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I am using wso2 SP 4.3.0 and i want extend strem processing with custom function.
I have follow this documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Writing+Custom+Siddhi+Extensions#WritingCustomSiddhiExtensions-siddhi-script so i created maven archetype, a modified logical function, and i created jar with maven build.

I moved .jar file in \lib but when i starting service wso2-editor console show me

[image]

How can i solve it?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find this solution

build my jar with this parameter

on parent pom i run mvn package with following parameter:
SkipTest
checkstyle.skip=true
findbugs.skip=true

this solution build a correct jar and solve for me.

Bye

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy the jar that is at /component/target. Above error is occurring because you have copied a jar for a place where SP is expecting a bundle.

Comment: Hi, i have copied .jar from /component/target into <SP_HOME>/lib directory. like doc  https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Writing+Custom+Siddhi+Extensions
Where is correct path to copy .jar file? do you know it?
Thank you

Comment: In that case can you please provide your custom jar so that I can have a look

Comment: Hi, you should find a .jar at [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11WwPz8Hrg36U91sFjJrEp1H-fv9N6dK1)
Thank you for support

Comment: I looked at your jar and there is an issue with the way jar is built. We are using apache Felix plugin to build a OSGi bundle. But when I checked the jar you shared there weren't any bundle related params in you Manifest file. Please confirm that you built the project executiing 'mvn clean install' at the project root level

Comment: I have tried to run mvn clean install but some error block me.
first error checkstyle validation so i run mvn install skip checkstyle
in second time error is [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs (findbugs) on project siddhi-execution-string: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs for parameter pluginArtifacts: Cannot assign configuration entry 'pluginArtifacts' with value '${plugin.artifacts}' of type java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to property of type java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Do you have an active internet connection for the machine that you are trying to build the project?